# Synchronizing threads from the same process

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have an assignment in which at first I have to make the following process tree:
[image]

I have succeeded in doing this, but after this I also have to create 4 threads with the following:

****Process P6 must create 4 threads: T6.1, T6.2, . . ., T6.4. You must impose on the
execution of the process P6’s threads the following synchronization conditions:**

**• Process’ main thread, i.e. T6.0 must not terminate before the other 4
threads.**

**• Thread T6.1 must start before T6.2 starts and terminate after T6.2 terminates.****

I have to introduce the header "a2_helper.h" and run my code with the help of the tester. The command to run the code is : **python3 tester.py**. I tried to implemented myself, but it isn't correct. The program is called : **a2.c**

This is what I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "a2_helper.h"

#define NR_THREADS 4
pthread_mutex_t mutex1, mutex2;

typedef struct thread_arg
{
   int process;
   int thread;
}th;

pid_t pid2, pid3, pid4, pid5, pid6, pid7, pid8;

void exect(th *thinfo)
{
   if (thinfo->process == 6 && thinfo->thread == 1)
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
   info(BEGIN, thinfo->process, thinfo->thread);
   if (thinfo->process == 6 && thinfo->thread == 2)
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
   if (thinfo->process == 6 && thinfo->thread == 2)
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
   info(END, thinfo->process, thinfo->thread);
   if (thinfo->process == 6 && thinfo->thread == 1)
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
}

void create_threads(pthread_t tid[], th thinfo[], int nr)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++){
       pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, (void *(*)(void *))exect, (void *)&thinfo[i]);
       }
   for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++){
       pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
       }
}

int create_process(int id)
{
   pid_t pid;
   if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
   {
       info(BEGIN, id, 0);

       if (id == 2)
       {
           pid6 = create_process(6);
           pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);
           pthread_mutex_init(&mutex2, NULL);
           pthread_t tid[NR_THREADS];
               th args[NR_THREADS] = {{6,1},{6,2},{6,3},{6,4}};
           create_threads(tid, args, 4);
           waitpid(pid6, 0, 0);
       }
       else if (id == 4)
       {
           pid7 = create_process(7);
           pthread_t tid[43];
           th args[43] = {{4,1},{4,2},{4,3},{4,4},{4,5},{4,6},{4,7},{4,8},{4,9},{4,10},
                   {4,11},{4,12},{4,13},{4,14},{4,15},{4,16},{4,17},{4,18},{4,19},{4,20},
                   {4,21},{4,22},{4,23},{4,24},{4,25},{4,26},{4,27},{4,28},{4,29},{4,30},
                   {4,31},{4,32},{4,33},{4,34},{4,35},{4,36},{4,37},{4,38},{4,39},{4,40},{4,41},{4,42},{4,43}};
           create_threads(tid, args, 43);
           waitpid(pid7, 0, 0);
       }
       else if (id == 5)
       {
           pid8 = create_process(8);
           waitpid(pid8, 0, 0);
       }
       info(END, id, 0);
       exit(0);
   }
   else return pid;
}

int main(){

   init();

   info(BEGIN, 1, 0);

   pid2 = create_process(2);
   pid3 = create_process(3);
   pid4 = create_process(4);
   pid5 = create_process(5);

   waitpid(pid2, 0, 0);
   waitpid(pid3, 0, 0);
   waitpid(pid4, 0, 0);
   waitpid(pid5, 0, 0);
           
   info(END, 1, 0);
   return 0;
}
```

This is a2_helper.h:

```
#ifndef __A2_HELPER_H__
#define __A2_HELPER_H__

#define BEGIN 1
#define END 2

void init();
int info(int action, int processNr, int threadNr);

#endif
```

This is a2_helper.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "a2_helper.h"

#define SEM_NAME "A2_HELPER_SEM_17871"
#define SERVER_PORT 1988

#define XSTR(s) STR(s)
#define STR(s) #s
#define CHECK(c) if(!(c)){perror("info function failed at line " XSTR(__LINE__)); break;}

int initialized = 0;

int info(int action, int processNr, int threadNr){
    int msg[6];
    int sleepTime = 0;
    int sockfd = -1;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    sem_t *sem = SEM_FAILED;
    int err = -1;

    if(initialized == 0){
        printf("init() function not called\n");
        return -1;
    }
    do{
        CHECK((sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, 0)) != SEM_FAILED);

        //prepare the message
        msg[0] = action;
        msg[1] = processNr;
        msg[2] = threadNr;
        msg[3] = getpid();
        msg[4] = getppid();
        msg[5] = pthread_self();

        CHECK((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) >= 0);
        
        memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

        CHECK(sem_wait(sem) == 0);
        err = -2;
        if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) >= 0){
            CHECK(write(sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg)) == sizeof(msg));
            CHECK(read(sockfd, &sleepTime, sizeof(sleepTime)) == sizeof(sleepTime));
            printf("[T] ");
        }else{
            printf("[ ] ");
        }
        printf("%s P%d T%d pid=%d ppid=%d tid=%d\n", msg[0]==BEGIN?"BEGIN":" END ", msg[1], msg[2], msg[3], msg[4], msg[5]);
        CHECK(sem_post(sem) == 0);
        err = -1;
        usleep(sleepTime);
        err = 0;
    }while(0);
    if(sockfd >= 0){
        close(sockfd);
    }
    if(err==-2){
        sem_post(sem);
    }
    return err;
}

void atfork_prepare(){
    sem_t *sem = SEM_FAILED;
    do{
        CHECK((sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)) != SEM_FAILED);
        CHECK(sem_wait(sem) == 0);
    }while(0);
}

void atfork_parent(){
    sem_t *sem = SEM_FAILED;
    do{
        CHECK((sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)) != SEM_FAILED);
        CHECK(sem_post(sem) == 0);
    }while(0);
}

void atfork_child(){
    prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP);
}

void init(){
    sem_t *sem = SEM_FAILED;
    if(initialized != 0){
        printf("init() function already called\n");
        return;
    }
    do{
        pthread_atfork(atfork_prepare, atfork_parent, atfork_child);
        sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
        CHECK((sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)) != SEM_FAILED);
        initialized = 1;
    }while(0);
}
```

This is tester.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re, os, sys, socket, struct, subprocess, json, base64
import threading, ctypes, ctypes.util, time

A2_PROG = "a2"
SEM_NAME = b"A2_HELPER_SEM_17871"
SERVER_PORT = 1988

VERBOSE = False
TIME_LIMIT = 3

def compile():
    if os.path.isfile(A2_PROG):
        os.remove(A2_PROG)
    LOG_FILE = "compile_log.txt"
    compLog = open(LOG_FILE, "w")
    subprocess.call(["gcc", "-Wall", "%s.c" % A2_PROG, "%s_helper.c" % A2_PROG, "-o", A2_PROG, "-pthread", "-lrt"], 
                        stdout=compLog, stderr=compLog)
    compLog.close()
    if os.path.isfile(A2_PROG):
        compLog = open(LOG_FILE)
        logContent = compLog.read()
        compLog.close()
        if "warning" in logContent:
            return 1
        return 2
    else:
        return 0

class Info:
    BEGIN = 1
    END = 2

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.proc = msg[1]
        self.th = msg[2]
        self.pid = msg[3]
        self.ppid = msg[4]
        self.tid = msg[5]
        self.timeStart = 0
        self.timeEnd = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "P%d T%d pid=%d ppid=%d tid=%d [%d - %d]" % (self.proc, self.th, 
                    self.pid, self.ppid, self.tid, self.timeStart, self.timeEnd)


class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.reset()
        self.shouldStop = False
        self.servSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.servSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.servSocket.bind(("localhost", SERVER_PORT))
        self.servSocket.listen(5)

    def reset(self):
        self.time = 0
        self.infos = {}
        self.errors = []
        self.delays = {}

    def addInfo(self, msg):
        i = Info(msg)
        key = (i.proc, i.th)
        if msg[0] != Info.BEGIN and msg[0] != Info.END:
            self.errors.append("unknonwn message type %d for process %d, thread %d" % (msg[0], i.proc, i.th))
            return -1
        key = (i.proc, i.th)
        if key in self.infos:
            if msg[0] == Info.BEGIN:
                self.errors.append("more than one BEGIN for process %d, thread %d" % (i.proc, i.th))
                return -1
            else:
                if self.infos[key].timeEnd != 0:
                    self.errors.append("more than one END for process %d, thread %d" % (i.proc, i.th))
                    return -1
                else:
                    self.time += 1
                    self.infos[key].timeEnd = self.time
        else:
            if msg[0] == Info.END:
                self.errors.append("END before BEGIN for process %d, thread %d" % (i.proc, i.th))
                return -1
            else:
                self.time += 1
                i.timeStart = self.time
                self.infos[key] = i
        if msg[0] == Info.BEGIN and key in self.delays:
            return self.delays[key]
        return 0


    def run(self):
        while True:
            (clientSocket, address) = self.servSocket.accept()
            if self.shouldStop:
                self.servSocket.close()
                break
            msg_size_remaining = 6 * 4
            msg = bytes()
            while msg_size_remaining != 0:
                current_buffer = clientSocket.recv(msg_size_remaining)
                if len(current_buffer) == 0:
                    break
                msg += current_buffer
                msg_size_remaining -= len(current_buffer)
            if len(msg) == 6 * 4:
                msg = struct.unpack("i"*6, msg)
                delay = self.addInfo(msg)
            else:
                delay = -10
            if delay < 0:
                # there was an error, we will stop the test
                clientSocket.sendall(struct.pack("i", 0))
            else:
                clientSocket.sendall(struct.pack("i", delay))

    def stop(self):
        self.shouldStop = True
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect(("localhost", SERVER_PORT))

def checkProcessHierarchy(data, infos):
    errors = []
    score = 0
    n = int(data["nrProcs"])
    procInfos = {}
    for (p, t), info in infos.items():
        if t == 0:
            if p >= 1 and p <= n:
                if info.timeEnd == 0:
                    errors.append("missing END for main thread of process %d" % p)
                    return errors, score
                else:
                    procInfos[p] = info
            else:
                errors.append("found unrequired process %d" % p)
                return errors, score
    if len(procInfos) < n:
        missing = []
        for p in range(1, n+1):
            if p not in procInfos:
                missing.append(str(p))
        errors.append("missing main thread for processes: " + (" ".join(missing)))
        return errors, score
    score += 2
    for p, info in procInfos.items():
        if p != 1:
            parent = int(data["procs"][str(p)])
            parentInfo = procInfos[parent]
            if info.ppid != parentInfo.pid:
                errors.append("the parent for process %d is not %d" % (p, parent))
            if info.timeStart < parentInfo.timeStart:
                errors.append("process %d starts before its parent %d" % (p, parent))
            if info.timeEnd > parentInfo.timeEnd:
                errors.append("process %d ends after its parent %d" % (p, parent))
    if len(errors) > 0:
        return errors, score
    score += 3
    return errors, score

def checkThreads1(data, infos):
    score = 0
    errors = []
    procNr = int(data["threads1_proc"])
    thCount = int(data["threads1_count"])
    thOuter = int(data["threads1_outer"])
    thInner = int(data["threads1_inner"])

    if (procNr, 0) in infos:
        mainTid = infos[(procNr, 0)].tid
    else:
        errors.append("main thread is missing for process %d" % procNr)
        return errors, score
    thInfos = {}
    for (p, t), info in infos.items():
        if p == procNr and t != 0:
            if t >= 1 and t <= thCount:
                if info.timeEnd == 0:
                    errors.append("missing END for thread %d in process %d" % (t, procNr))
                    return errors, score
                elif info.tid == mainTid:
                    errors.append("thread T%d.%d is the same as the main thread of the process" % (procNr, t))
                    return errors, score
                else:
                    thInfos[t] = info
            else:
                errors.append("found unrequired thread %d in process %d" % (t, procNr))
                return errors, score
    if len(thInfos) > 0:
        score += 1
    if len(thInfos) < thCount:
        missing = []
        for t in range(1, thCount+1):
            if t not in thInfos:
                missing.append(str(t))
        errors.append("missing threads %s in process %d" % (" ".join(missing), procNr))
        return errors, score
    score += 1
    if thInfos[thOuter].timeStart < thInfos[thInner].timeStart:
        score += 1
    else:
        errors.append("thread T%d.%d starts after T%d.%d" % (procNr, thOuter, procNr, thInner))
    if thInfos[thOuter].timeEnd > thInfos[thInner].timeEnd:
        score += 1
    else:
        errors.append("thread T%d.%d ends before T%d.%d" % (procNr, thOuter, procNr, thInner))
    if score == 4:
        score = 5
    return errors, score

def checkThreads2(data, infos):
    score = 0
    errors = []
    procNr = int(data["threads2_proc"])
    thCount = int(data["threads2_count"])
    thWaiter = int(data["threads2_waiter"])
    maxThreads = int(data["threads2_max"])

    if (procNr, 0) in infos:
        mainTid = infos[(procNr, 0)].tid
    else:
        errors.append("main thread is missing for process %d" % procNr)
        return errors, score
    thInfos = {}
    for (p, t), info in infos.items():
        if p == procNr and t != 0:
            if t >= 1 and t <= thCount:
                if info.timeEnd == 0:
                    errors.append("missing END for thread %d in process %d" % (t, procNr))
                    return errors, score
                elif info.tid == mainTid:
                    errors.append("thread T%d.%d is the same as the main thread of the process" % (procNr, t))
                    return errors, score
                else:
                    thInfos[t] = info
            else:
                errors.append("found unrequired thread %d in process %d" % (t, procNr))
                return errors, score
    if len(thInfos) < thCount:
        missing = []
        for t in range(1, thCount+1):
            if t not in thInfos:
                missing.append(str(t))
        errors.append("missing thread(s) %s in process %d" % (" ".join(missing), procNr))
        return errors, score
    score += 1

    times = {}
    for info in thInfos.values():
        for t in range(info.timeStart, info.timeEnd+1):
            if t not in times:
                times[t] = []
            times[t].append(info.th)
    violation = False
    for t in sorted(times.keys()):
        if len(times[t]) > maxThreads:
            errors.append("the following threads are running at the same time: %s" % 
                                " ".join([str(th) for th in times[t]]))
            violation = True
            break
    if not violation:
        score += 1
    waiterGroup = times[thInfos[thWaiter].timeEnd]
    if len(waiterGroup) != maxThreads:
        errors.append("the following threads are running while ending thread T%d.%d: %s" % 
                                (procNr, thWaiter, " ".join([str(th) for th in waiterGroup])))
    else:
        score += 1

    if score == 3:
        score = 5
    return errors, score

def checkThreads3(data, infos):
    score = 0
    errors = []
    procNr = int(data["threads3_proc"])
    thCount = int(data["threads3_count"])
    thBefore = int(data["threads3_before"])
    thAfter = int(data["threads3_after"])
    proc1 = int(data["threads1_proc"])
    proc1Th = int(data["threads1_3"])

    if (procNr, 0) in infos:
        mainTid = infos[(procNr, 0)].tid
    else:
        errors.append("main thread is missing for process %d" % procNr)
        return errors, score
    thInfos = {}
    for (p, t), info in infos.items():
        if p == procNr and t != 0:
            if t >= 1 and t <= thCount:
                if info.timeEnd == 0:
                    errors.append("missing END for thread %d in process %d" % (t, procNr))
                    return errors, score
                elif info.tid == mainTid:
                    errors.append("thread T%d.%d is the same as the main thread of the process" % (procNr, t))
                    return errors, score
                else:
                    thInfos[t] = info
            else:
                errors.append("found unrequired thread %d in process %d" % (t, procNr))
                return errors, score
    if len(thInfos) < thCount:
        missing = []
        for t in range(1, thCount+1):
            if t not in thInfos:
                missing.append(str(t))
        errors.append("missing threads %s in process %d" % (" ".join(missing), procNr))
        return errors, score
    score += 1
    if (proc1, proc1Th) not in infos:
        errors.append("thread %d is missing from process %d" % (proc1Th, proc1))
        return errors, score
    info1 = infos[(proc1, proc1Th)]
    if info1.timeStart > thInfos[thBefore].timeEnd:
        score += 1
    else:
        errors.append("thread T%d.%d starts before T%d.%d ended" % (proc1, proc1Th, procNr, thBefore))
    if info1.timeEnd < thInfos[thAfter].timeStart:
        score += 1
    else:
        errors.append("thread T%d.%d ends after T%d.%d started" % (proc1, proc1Th, procNr, thAfter))
    if score == 3:
        score = 5
    
    return errors, score

class Tester(threading.Thread):
    CHECK_FUNCTIONS = [
                        (checkProcessHierarchy, "process hierarchy"),
                        (checkThreads1, "threads from the same process"),
                        (checkThreads2, "threads barrier"),
                        (checkThreads3, "threads from different processes")
                    ]
    CHECK_MAX_SCORE = 5

    def __init__(self, nr, server, data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("\033[1;35mTest %d...\033[0m" % nr)
        self.server = server
        self.cmd = ["./%s" % A2_PROG]
        self.timeLimit = TIME_LIMIT
        self.result = None
        self.p = None
        self.data = data
        self.delays = {}

        # add delays for leaf processes
        if nr in (2, 3, 4):
            for p in self.data["procs"]:
                if p not in self.data["procs"].values():
                    self.delays[(int(p), 0)] = nr * 40000
        # add delays for "Synchronizing threads from the same process"
        if nr in (2, 4):
            p1 = int(self.data["threads1_proc"])
            #to = int(self.data["threads1_outer"])
            ti = int(self.data["threads1_inner"])
            self.delays[(p1, ti)] = 100000 * nr
        # add delays for "Synchronizing threads from different processes"
        if nr in (3, 4):
            p1 = int(self.data["threads1_proc"])
            p3 = int(self.data["threads3_proc"])
            tw = int(self.data["threads1_3"])
            tb = int(self.data["threads3_before"])
            #ta = int(self.data["threads3_after"])
            self.delays[(p3, tb)] = 50000 * nr
            self.delays[(p1, tw)] = 70000 * nr
        # add delays for "Threads barrier"
        if nr in (2, 3):
            p2 = int(self.data["threads2_proc"])
            p2_count = int(self.data["threads2_count"])
            tw = int(self.data["threads2_waiter"])
            if nr == 2:
                self.delays[(p2, tw)] = 250000
            elif nr == 3:
                for t in range(1, p2_count+1):
                    if t != tw:
                        self.delays[(p2, t)] = 10000
        # add delays to enforce concurrency in "Threads barrier"
        if nr == 5:
            p2 = int(self.data["threads2_proc"])
            p2_count = int(self.data["threads2_count"])
            d = 2 * TIME_LIMIT * 1000000 // p2_count
            for t in range(1, p2_count+1):
                self.delays[(p2, t)] = d

    def run(self):
        self.server.reset()
        self.server.delays = self.delays
        if VERBOSE:
            self.p = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd)
        else:
            self.p = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=open(os.devnull, "w"))
        self.p.wait()

    def perform(self):
        timeout = False
        self.start()
        self.join(self.timeLimit)

        if self.is_alive():
            if self.p is not None:
                self.p.kill()
                timeout = True
            self.join()

        if timeout:
            print("\t\033[1;31mTIME LIMIT EXCEEDED\033[0m")
            return 0, Tester.CHECK_MAX_SCORE * len(Tester.CHECK_FUNCTIONS)

        score = 0
        for err in self.server.errors:
            print("\t%s" % err)
        if len(self.server.errors) == 0:
            for checkFn, checkName in Tester.CHECK_FUNCTIONS:
                print("\tChecking %s..." % checkName)
                errors, testScore = checkFn(self.data, self.server.infos)
                for err in errors:
                    print("\t\t%s" % err)
                if testScore == Tester.CHECK_MAX_SCORE:
                    print("\t\t\033[1;32mCORRECT        \033[0m", end="")
                elif testScore > 0:
                    print("\t\t\033[1;33mPARTIAL CORRECT\033[0m", end="")
                else:
                    print("\t\t\033[1;31mFAIL           \033[0m", end="")
                print(" [%d point(s)]" % testScore)
                score += testScore

        return score, Tester.CHECK_MAX_SCORE * len(Tester.CHECK_FUNCTIONS)


def resetSemaphore():
    O_CREAT = 0x0200
    _lib = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library("pthread"))
    #_sem_open = _lib.sem_open
    #_sem_open.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_uint)
    _sem_unlink = _lib.sem_unlink
    _sem_unlink.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, )

    _sem_unlink(SEM_NAME)
    #_sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)



def main():
    compileRes = compile()
    if compileRes == 0:
        print("COMPILATION ERROR")
    else:
        score = 0
        resetSemaphore()
        serv = Server()
        serv.start()

        with open("a2_data.json") as a2_data:
            content = a2_data.read()
            decoded_data = base64.b64decode(content).decode('utf-8')
            data = json.loads(decoded_data)

        score = 0
        maxScore = 0
        for t in range(1,6):
            tester = Tester(t, serv, data)
            testScore, testMaxScore = tester.perform()
            score += testScore
            maxScore += testMaxScore
        serv.stop()
        print("Total score: %d / %d" % (score, maxScore))
        score = 100.0 * score / maxScore
        if compileRes == 1:
            print("\033[1;31mThere were some compilation warnings. A 10% penalty will be applied.\033[0m")
            score = score * 0.9
        print("Assignment grade: %.2f / 100" % score)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

a2_helper.c, a2_helper.h, tester.py were already implemented and I only have to use them.

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are asking. "I tried to implemented myself, but it isn't correct" isn't a good description of the problem. I can't even tell whether your problem is in the C code or the python code

Comment: Your `create_process()` function recursively calls itself with (in different cases) arguments 6, 7, and 8.  However, the function does not have specific cases for those calls, so they will exhibit the default behavior.  In particular, process 6 will not start any threads -- it looks like you have process 2 doing that.

Comment: Every cast for other than arithmetic reasons has bad code smell.  Whatever problems you think your casts in `create_threads()` are solving, they either should be solved differently or they don't actually exist in the first place.

Comment: I think you'll find a semaphore easier to use than a mutex for synchronizing on thread 6.1 actually starting.  If you cannot use a semaphore then you'll want a condition variable in addition to a mutex.  Also you should need only one semaphore or one mutex + CV pair, though of course you can do the job with two if you like.

Comment: @4386427 in the C code, I don't know how to implement the requirement. The python code is correct, I don't have to modify it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can use a semaphore too. I understand that process6 won't start the 2 threads, but can I modify this code somehow, because I don't really know how to solve the problem with a semaphore.

Comment: @Emma, it's a question of one thread signaling another.  In order to ensure that thread 6.2 does not start before thread 6.1 has done, thread 6.1 needs to positively inform thread 6.0 when it actually has started (because that hasn't necessarily happened yet when the `pthread_create()` call returns).  Incrementing a semaphore whose initial value is 0 is one way to do that.  Meanwhile, thread 6.0 tries to decrement the semaphore, and it will block until it can do so.

Comment: The reverse can be done for thread 6.0 to inform thread 6.1 that thread 6.2 has terminated (which 6.0 determines by successfully joining 6.2).  With POSIX semaphores, it's probably easier to use a separate semaphore for that, though with some other implementations, a single one will do the job.  You can implement the same kind of signaling pattern with mutexes and condition variables, but correct use of those is more complicated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you very much, I will try to solve it this way!!